# How to get the correct string for the ascii value greater that 127 ( for eg:130) in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to send the Ascii value for an integer greater that 127 to encrypt the string. I'm using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", myInteger]`. However, this return an empty string probably because myInteger is greater than 127, e.g 130.

Comment: Try a capital `C` instead of lowercase in your format string.

Comment: They are non-printable characters. you should make a range of acceptable values. Or invent encryption techinique yourself or simple use `AES`

Comment: Ok.Is any possibilities to change the ascii 130 to unicode Ç

Comment: The way you are using is perfectly correct. I think some of the characters are non-printable, thats why not showing it, try characters 224,225 etc.. they get printed too.